# Core Plot, custom labels and tick marks

Tags: core-plot

I am using Core Plot alpha release 0.2 and generating a plot with custom labels. The labels are appearing in the correct location but I have no tick marks. I have tried every combination of these settings:

x.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"] decimalValue];
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
x.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
x.tickDirection=CPSignNegative;

I've also added padding to the bottom of the graph using:

graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=10.0;

which has the effect of moving the X axis 'up' but no tick marks are visible. This seems like it should be pretty simple, generate a tick mark at the location of the custom label. But I don't see any way to do it.

Ideas?

****** Here's the code I'm using to generate the labels and tick marks, with no luck *******

```
for (int i = 0; i < [xAxisLabels count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary * labelDict = [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *label=[labelDict valueForKey:@"element"];

    NSNumber *offset=[labelDict valueForKey:@"x"];

    float location=[offset floatValue]*multiplier; 
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: label textStyle:labelStyle]; 
    newLabel.tickLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(location); 
    newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    [customTicks addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPDecimalFromFloat(location)]];
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [newLabel release];
}
x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
[x setMinorTickLocations:[NSSet setWithArray:customTicks]];
[x setMajorTickLocations:[NSSet setWithArray:customTicks]];
[customTicks release];
```

Answer (score 1):

With `CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone` you need to provide the tick locations (`minorTickLocations` and `majorTickLocations`), too.

Comment: No luck. I updated my question with a code snippet showing how I'm trying to add the ticks.